# WiFi module communication with Android Phone

Tags: android, wifi, gpio

I am working on a project which is an android controlled LED light. This LED is connected to a LED controller, which is connected to a WiFi module ([WizFi220](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/Sub_Modules/en/product/Product_Detail.asp?cate1=&cate2=&cate3=&pid=1134)). WiFi module uses GPIO interface to send data to LED controller.
The Android phone sends data through TCPSocket.

Until now I achieved to write a simple Server-Client communication, and the server was implemented in Java, on a normal PC. It worked well. (eg if I pushed a button on the android device, the Server program on the PC printed out something to the console)

The question is what should I send to the WizFi module to be understandable... if it comes out from the GPIO interface, the "command" reaches the LED controller, eg it turns on/off, changes color or anything. (as the LED is RGB LEDs)

Thanks for answers and help.

Comment: Hello Peter,  I am working on same example. do you have any tutorial?? i am not able to communicate between WizFi200 and android. Please help me.

Comment: Hello @AmolSawant96Kuli, I do not have any tutorial. In the Wizfi220 manual:[link](http://wiznet.co.kr/UpLoad_Files/ReferenceFiles/WizFi210-QuickStartGuide_EN_V1.0.pdf) You can see the full setup of the module. If you were successful, and you can see its ip/name combo in router's active connected devices, than it is easy to send any type of package with Java/Android. It was some years ago, when i did this, but i figured out what kind of UDP packages were went by its reference application (WizsmartScript) then I copied them. Wireshark can be used to capture sent packages. If you have qs pls ask

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks for replying. I did successfully communication between WizFi220 and android. WizFi module receiving data easily whatever sent by android device but, Android not able to receive data by WizFi module. Is there any idea about this?? we are not able to find out where is a actual problem at Android end or at WizFi end. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: When I did this, i only used one-way communication, only giving AT-commands over WiFi from android to WizFi. And it was in commmand mode, so actually i did not really used the data mode. So sorry, i do not have any experience with it. But as I know it should work if you setup wifi modul with AT commands...